# How to connect to a third party REST API using OAuth?

Tags: rest-api, rest, oauth2

I have a third party REST API that needs to be called from Salesforce, using OAuth for authentication. Is this actually possible? If so, how? I really can't find anything useful on the web. For me, it seems that I would have to build this myself.

Comment: I believe you are looking for Named credentials
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_callouts_named_credentials.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the "named credential" feature  http://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=named_credentials_about.htm&language=en_US

With named credentials the Oauth2 authentication flow is handled automatically, you don't need to implement specific code for it.

Comment: I'm trying to get this to work. I have a client credential grant that is working elsewhere but I have absolutely no clue how to do this with a named credential.